# React [antd] collapse not working correctly when using [react-sortable-hoc] dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-sortable-hoc

I'm using ant design in a react project, and I want to sort some panels with Drag & Drop, but when I try to map the panels inside the collapse, they do not open anymore.
Example in: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bogdan-56si1?file=/src/App.js

thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Great job with the sand box link. It always helps when you also post your code here, so people don't have to open another link if they don't want to.

Comment: Hi @Souhail I am also facing the same issue. Using ANTD collapse and trying to sort it using react-sortable-hoc. Did you find solution? If yes, would you mind sharing answer?

Answer (score -3):

You need to add props to Panel [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-knuth-qwrx5)

Comment: Sorting is not happening in your example code.